# How to achieve this effect in Illustrator/Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop-effects, texture, illustrator-effects

So, I wanted to redesign the jersey of the teams in football. But then I found the design which I think is quite difficult to make but beautiful to see. Did anyone know, how to make the design below? I've tried with a brush, but I did not managed to. Perhaps there is an automatic way?

[image: NIKE USA National Team Kit]

Comment: What part exactly? The kind of gradient? The "textile texture"?

Comment: the graphic pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of effect is known as a 'noise gradient' and can be achieved in Photoshop as follows:

1. Select the `Gradient` tool;
2. Click the example gradient in the toolbar to have a dialog box open;
3. Change the `Gradient type` from `Solid` to `Noise`;
4. Set the colour model to `HSB`;
5. Allow H(ue) to be anything between cyan and blue; S(aturation) the entire range and B(rightness) only the top 10%;
6. Hit <kbd>Randomize</kbd> until you are content;
7. Hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]

You can then use the gradient tool to draw your new preset gradient wherever you want, or use it as a gradient overlay or fill.

You also might want to fiddle with the 'Roughness' level to get the gradient you want.

For the design in your image, probably some other effect were used as well to make the pattern non-uniform in the horizontal direction, where a noise gradient is uniform. They probably blended multiple gradients together with layer masks to achieve that effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy, it's very similar to creating a brocade in photoshop

http://www.slicktutorials.com/quick-and-easy-barcode

The process is similar but when you creating the noise, you can do it not in monochromatic...

And here is another option to create this, maybe even better:

http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-create-a-barcode-sticker-in-photoshop--psd-8400

[image]

In both of the links there are tutorials on how to create a barcode in photoshop. the barcode is just a number of random width lines.
If you follow this tutorials you can then rotate 90 degrees the barcode and change its color with a regular gradient (masked).
and finally place them on your shirt design, similar to the example.

Comment: Hi dimshik, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the links you provided and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

Comment: @AndrewH Added an explenation on how to use the tutorials to create the staring point of the wanted design